# How to possible withloop & autoplay carousel in angular 2+

Tags: jquery, html, angular, npm, npm-package

[image]

I'm working angular 8. Please suggest image carousel also customize inside carousel images for small devices. Thank you!

Comment: Use owl carousel

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ngx-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gallery)** or **[ngx-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel/v/1.2.0)** **npm package**. Both having good features to customize accordingly.

Hope this helps.